# pylance(reportMissingModuleSource) error in VS Code while using Django

Tags: python, django, pylance

[https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/master/docs/configuration.md"](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/master/docs/configuration.md%22)
The error directs to this GitHub readme, no clarification, and no solution is given for this error
[The Error Message Shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnT5l.jpg)

I reinstall python and Django again still not working. What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

This could be because you are not using the correct python interpreter for your venv.

To select the interpreter: "View" > "Command Palette" or (Ctrl+Shift+P) and search and select "Python: Select Interpreter".

Then enter the path to the correct Python interpreter in your venv. Example:

```
./.venv/bin/python3
```

More here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django#_create-a-project-environment-for-the-django-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

To remove pylance(reportMissingModuleSource) error in VS Code follow these steps:

- In VS Code, open the Command Palette (View > Command Palette or (⇧⌘P)).
- Select the Python.
- Select Interpreter command.
- The command presents a list of available interpreters that VS Code can locate automatically (Your list will vary. If you don't see the desired interpreter, see Configuring Python environments). From the list, select the virtual environment in your project folder that starts with `./.venv` or `.\.venv`.