Prettytable import returning Pylance(reportMissingModuleSource) error
A friend of mine has tried to import PrettyTable into their VS Code, but even after installing it in the terminal it only returns a Pylance(reportMissingModuleSource) error message.
We have tried a different table import, but it seems all their imports are not working as each one we try returns the same error. I tried adding a path in her settings as I had seen on another forum post but it did not seem to work (though I probably did it wrong because I am not good with coding programs haha)
Does anyone seem to have a fix to this issue and could please share the steps to solve this? We are both not good with code and instructions would be greatly appreciated lol
EDIT: have been told that the question is a bit unclear. When we try installing through pip with the usual install code:
python -m pip install -U prettytable

it says that it has successfully installed (requirement satisfied), but when we try to use the run code:
from prettytable import PrettyTable

it only returns the error message from above. This is the issue for most of the modules we tried to install, but the random module works fine.

Could you possibly include the entire error message? I think that would be very helpful for finding a fix to this issue. Additionally check the top answer here as it seems similar to your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68835591/16169432

This is a very commonly asked question. As someone new to Python, you might want to ignore such error messages for now, especially if your code "works".

It seems that you installed the package into wrong path. You can use which python command in VSCode terminal to check which python interpreter you are currently using before installing the packages for your project.
